# Displaying complex data in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class that I use to display quite a complex set of data.

Essentially the cell displays a `Match` object. But in doing so it displays information about the two `Teams`, the score, the time elapsed and so on.

Thinking about MVC and clean code.

Should I just pass in the `Match` object and let the cell do everything? Or is it better practise to expose the different elements of the cell (team1NameLabel, team1ScoreLabel, team2NameLabel, etc...) and set them all individually in the `UITableViewController`?

The first way makes the `UITableViewController` cleaner but then I'm relying on the `UITableViewCell` to "know" about the `Match` class, the `Team` class etc...

The second way makes more work for the `UITableViewController` but then makes the `UITableViewCell` a "dumb" display. All it does is then lay out the information within the cell. It doesn't know anything about the information it is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow these rules:

- The cell should just have the outlets for displaying the various bits of data. It is a view so it should not contain any logic.
- The controller should get the `Match` data, parse and make calculations if necessary, and populate the cell. It is a controller, so that is its primary function in a MVC context.

Comment: Excellent, I was leaning toward this myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IMO  it is better and more MVC-like to pass the `Match` object to your table view cell.

Lot of the code you find on the internet(even Apple examples if I remember well) is not doing that. You can see many times a configureCell method within the view controller that is called in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I prefer to pass the model object object to the cell, it makes my view controller code simpler and also it is simpler to unit test: when I test my view controller I only verify that the model object is passed to the cell, and then in the table view cell tests I verify that the test of the labels is set to the expected values. Someone may say that this is making the view knowing about the model, but I don't see any big problem on that.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are fine, but personally I would go for second option, i.e. table view exposing @property and, if necessary, outlets.

However, if you really want to go for the first option, I would suggest to have any objects passed to the cell to implements a protocol exposing few methods:

```
@protocol tableViewCellProtocol

    -(NSString*)titleForCell;
    -(NSString*)descriptionForCell;
```

Then you can "pass the protocol" rather than the object.

```
[mytableCell renderObject:objectImplementingProtocol];
```

This way you slightly decouple the objects itself, and prepare cell for reuse with other objects.